Initiate push to local machine from Google Drive
I have a Sheets app script that does a number of things but finishes by creating 4 flat files on my Google Drive.
I'd like to extend this by pushing the created files to my local machine immediately after they are created.
I'm having trouble finding information on how to initiate the push to my local Windows box. Can someone provide skeleton code or point me to some docs that would help?
